# Git not tracking new files - is tracking existing

Tags: git

Finally going to give up and ask for help.  Having some git (windows) issues.  If I make changes to an existing file,I can add-commit-push as usual.  However, if I create a new file, git does not track it at all.  Regardless of folder or extension.  I am quite certain this is not a gitignore issue.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Welcome to SU! We'll need some more details before we can help you. Do you mean `git add` doesn't work on new files? Have you verified that those files are not omitted by your `.gitignore`?

Comment: i don't see anything in the .gitignore that should exclude them.  although when I do a git check-ignore, it returs: .gitifnore:2:*, but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: If you look in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore), you'll see that `.gitignore:2:*` means that on the second line of your .gitignore file, you've told git to ignore `*`, which amounts to all the files in that folder.